# SQL Server 2008 scripting wizard not creating database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to use the scripting wizard in SQL Server 2008 to generate a copy of the whole database

It seems to have worked before because I have generated scripts including both the `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements, but now I am only getting the `CREATE TABLE` scripts.

I know I can script creating the database separately and chain the statements together, but have I missed an option that automatically includes the `CREATE DATABASE` script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you choose the option "**Script entire database and all database objects**" in the wizard. database creation is part of the script.
And in the advanced section i don't see an option to exclude Database creation.however there are lot of other things you can configure there.

Answer (score 0):

I know its very late to respond to this question. I faced this issue recently. There is an option in the advanced section "Script Database Create" which will be false by default. Make it as true and it will add create database script also. Thank you.